# What is the word or set-phrases of "grinding/grindy gameplay" as opposed to "power-leveling" in formal/informal Japanese

Tags: translation, words, word-requests, phrase-requests

Background: Japanese online games are known for its **grinding** process while people often find a way to "power-level" in a certain way so that they can bypass the '**grindy** process'.

I have difficulties in conveying "This online game is too **grindy** that it isn't worth your time" as opposed to "power-leveling"...

[image]

^ **

> How to do you explain this picture in Japanese?

**

The problem is that I can't find a good example and an exact counterpart of Japanese word of '**grindy**' which convey not only upgrading and honing the skills, but also the enormous effort to reach a simple goal in an online game.

Most of the dictionary definition is about grinding process instead of grindy (https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/grindy: (video games, informal) Involving a lot of repetition in order to progress.)

Result (no result):

- **Jisho: https://jisho.org/search/grindy =  ...**
- Yahoojp:
     https://dic.yahoo.co.jp/search/?p=grindy&stype=prefix&aq=-1&oq=&ei=UTF-8
- goo.ne.jp: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/grindy/m0u/
- alc.co.jp: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=grindy
- weblio:
     https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/grindy (no definition)

Finally a lead and found a close (probably) rendition (is this okay?):

Grinding levels:

**> レベル上げ - noun**

**> レベル上げをする - verb**

**> (insert a Japanese word/phrase) - adjective**

Grinding experiences:

**> 経験値稼ぎ - noun**

**> 経験値稼ぎをする - verb**

**> (insert a Japanese word/phrase) - adjective**

**[Source](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/476977)**

Please help and explain in the (most) thorough way (and probably an example or two will do).
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that definition on weblio ("involving a lot of reputation") is incorrect? Can I assume *grindy* is a synonym for *repetitive*?

Comment: No, it is just not there. Hmm, not quite repetitive, since repetitive focuses on the process (repeating, not necessarily hard) while grindy focuses on the strenuous effort to make such repetitive task (usually difficult task because that is boring and repetitive, "consumes" a lot of time), thus grindy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is 作業感の強いゲーム (formal) or [作業ゲー](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E4%BD%9C%E6%A5%AD%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC) (slang).

In gaming contexts, 作業 (literally "task") is a common word which refers to that repetitive and boring work such as defeating the same enemy many times to level up. 作業 is basically a negative word in this context, and many people dislike it. But there are popular games whose main enjoyment is 作業 itself, so 作業 is not 100% negative. For example, [*Cookie Clicker*](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) is a typical 作業ゲー but is loved by many people.

レベル上げ and 経験値稼ぎ is definitely a kind of 作業, but they only refer to leveling/exp-grinding.

I don't know how you came up with ガリ勉, but it has nothing to do with games.

Comment: ガリ勉 -> I saw it on some online news about Japan, so I thought it might come close but I was totally wrong